# `pserve development.ini` gives traceback ImportError: No module named testsite

Tags: python, docker, gunicorn, pyramid

I have a Pyramid project I am trying to migrate to Docker from VBox. When I attempt to startup the Gunicorn WSGI server with `pserve development.ini`

I get this **traceback**:

```
> /app/venv/bin/pserve /app/testsite_config/development.ini --reload 
---> Running in 72665248bbeb

Starting monitor for PID 12.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hupper/ipc.py", line 315, in spawn_main
    func(**kwargs)
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hupper/worker.py", line 267, in worker_main
    func(*spec_args, **spec_kwargs)
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 32, in main
    return command.run()
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 253, in run
    app = loader.get_wsgi_app(app_name, config_vars)
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/plaster_pastedeploy/__init__.py", line 131, in get_wsgi_app
    global_conf=defaults)
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 253, in loadapp
    return loadobj(APP, uri, name=name, **kw)
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 277, in loadobj
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 302, in loadcontext
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 326, in _loadconfig
    return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 455, in get_context
    global_additions=global_additions)
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 564, in _pipeline_app_context
    APP, pipeline[-1], global_conf)
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 459, in get_context
    section)
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 481, in _context_from_use
    object_type, name=use, global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 412, in get_context
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 302, in loadcontext
    global_conf=global_conf)
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 334, in _loadegg
    return loader.get_context(object_type, name, global_conf)
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 625, in get_context
    object_type, name=name)
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 651, in find_egg_entry_point
    possible.append((entry.load(), protocol, entry.name))
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2324, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/app/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2330, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
ImportError: No module named testsite
Server with PID 12 exited with code 1.
Waiting for changes before reloading.
```

This is my **development.ini** file:

```
[app:testsite]
use = egg:testsite
reload_templates = true
debug_authorization = false
debug_notfound = false
debug_routematch = false
debug_templates = true
default_locale_name = en
pyramid.includes = pyramid_debugtoolbar
                   pyramid_tm
                   pyramid_mailer

jinja2.directories = testsite:templates

#SQlalchemy configuration (The prefix `sqlalchemy.` can be changed IF you change it in __init__.py's engine_from_config() call too
# database
sqlalchemy.url = sqlite:///%(here)s/testsite.db
#sqlalchemy.pool_recycle = 3600
#sqlalchemy.pool_size = 20



# email testsite list
email_list = %(here)s/email_list.txt



[pipeline:main]
pipeline =
    testsite

[server:main]
use = egg:Pyramid#wsgiref
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 6543

# Begin logging configuration

[loggers]
keys = root, testsite

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = INFO
handlers = console

[logger_testsite]
level = DEBUG
handlers =
qualname = testsite

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s][%(threadName)s] %(message)s

# End logging configuration
```

This is my **setup.py**:

```
import os

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
#README = open(os.path.join(here, 'README.txt')).read()
#CHANGES = open(os.path.join(here, 'CHANGES.txt')).read()

requires=['pyramid>=1.4',
          'pyramid_jinja2',
          'jinja2',
          'jinja2_alchemy_starter',
          'sqlalchemy',
          'waitress',
          'pyramid_tm',
          'pyramid_debugtoolbar',
          'pyramid_mailer',
          'zope.sqlalchemy']

setup(name='testsite',
      version='0.0',
      description='testsite',
#      long_description=README + '\n\n' +  CHANGES,
      classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python",
        "Framework :: Pylons",
        "Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP",
        "Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP :: WSGI :: Application",
        ],
      author='',
      author_email='',
      url='',
      keywords='web pyramid pylons',
      packages=find_packages(),
      include_package_data=True,
      zip_safe=False,
      install_requires=requires,
      tests_require=requires,
      test_suite="testsite",
      entry_points = """\
      [paste.app_factory]
      main = testsite:main
      """,
      paster_plugins=['pyramid'],
      )
```

To replicate everything exactly, here is the Docker container (https://github.com/rajsinghUSA/testsite), which I build using this line:

> docker build -t image_from_dockerfile -f testsite.Dockerfile .

Comment: `ImportError: No module named testsite` means you have not installed your app `testsite`. However you did that in VBox, you need to do the same in Docker in your app's `Dockerfile`.

Comment: @StevePiercy I do run `pip install -e .` (you can see here https://github.com/rajsinghUSA/testsite/blob/master/testsite.Dockerfile#L19) and the same happens if I do `python setup.py develop`.

Comment: What does the docker log show? Do not use `python setup.py develop`. If you mix setuptools and pip installation methods together, then your virtual environment will be in a bad state.

Comment: @StevePiercy the log doesn't seem to show any additional information other than the traceback: https://paste.ee/p/Gi7WJ

Comment: Very sorry, my example app was the issue since I didn't have a testsite/__init__.py in there. That was the reason the testsite module couldn't be found.